# Response surface design for factors with two levels

Tags: experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I would like to fit a response surface to a system (actually, a computer model of a complex physical system) with 15 parameters that can be either on or off (ie 2 levels only).  There could be interactions between the parameters, so the response surface would have to include terms of the form `xi * xj`.  There could therefore be up to 225 terms in the response surface (hopefully fewer ...) so I will need at least 225 runs.  My question is how should I choose these runs?

It is impractical to run a full-factorial design on this system and AFAIK Box-Behnken designs need 3 levels so I would be grateful for any advice on (a) how many runs to select and (b) how to set the parameters during each run.  I did follow the suggestions in this post
[Full and fractional factorial designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77057/full-and-fractional-factorial-designs)

But got this error message from R

```
Nullifcation failed to find a starting design.
```

Comment: Is it meaningful to include a centerpoint?

Comment: No - the system represents wells which are either on or off

Comment: Then it is a (fractional) factorial design, response surface designs is used with continuous  variables, so that the response function can actually be thought of (and plotted) as a surface.  If you have any idea about which interactions could be important, and which could be safely ignored, then tell us about that, which will be important for constructing a design!

Comment: Hi Kjetil - not really ... I suspect that there are interactions between wells so don't know a prioiri what they are.  In fact, I was hoping that the coefficients of the terms xi * xj in the response surface would give some insight into this

Comment: Well, they will ... 2^15= 32768  so unless you can afford 32768 experimental runs you will need a fractional factorial, and some knowledge about probable interactions/noninteractions can be used to choose a good fraction! without such information you can as well choose whatever fraction... but at least some informed guess about likely or important interactions could be used! What a fractiuonal factorial does is to *group* interaction parameters and then estimate the *sum* of the parameters in each group, so is good for prediction, but cannot be used to *identify* interactions within the groups

Comment: No, those runs would take about 7 1/2 years to make ... and I don't have much insight into interactions.  I think it's back to the drawing board.  I might try a 24 factor PB design and see what that does.  Thanks for your help